# How do I use the property table for thermodynamics for water?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, water, physical-chemistry, phase-diagram

When to use the saturated water table and when to use the superheated water table? Also, please mention when to use the pressure table and when the temperature table?

Comment: I believe this site describes what you want to know: http://athena.ecs.csus.edu/~reardonf/ThermoNotesI/tablproc04.htm

Comment: @BobD I believe It is, I have to check with my Thermodynamics book for more information. 
Do you happen to know what is the formula for the entropy change in the Adiabetic system? I know the surrounding entropy will be zero but what is the change inside the system?

Comment: Is the change reversible?

Comment: For a reversible adiabatic (isentropic) process the entropy change of the system is zero. For an irreversible process you need to devise any convenient reversible process that connects the initial and final states 1 & 2 and then calculate the entropy change using $$\Delta S=\int_1^2\frac{\delta q_{rev}}{T}$$

Comment: @ChetMiller No it's not. Here's the question link 
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/669057/formula-of-entropy