# Formula of Entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Please, clear my confusion as to why this formula in an exam paper is written this way? Also, is/are there any way to calculate the difference of entropy? If I want to use the property tables of thermodynamics, which should I use?

[image]

Comment: Since entropies are additive we can subtract entropies simply by subtracting them. It's no more difficult than that.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Okay but can I use thermodynamics property tables such as ideal properties of air to get the value of s_1 and s_2?

Comment: Are you not familiar with the equation for the change in entropy of an ideal gas between states T1, V1 and T2,V2?

Comment: To do this using tables, you use the thermodynamic tables for air.

Comment: @ChetMiller Yes, I am, But I want to explore other options as sometimes the application of formulas confuses me. 
Which one should I use? Pressure or Temperature Table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the definition of the change of entropy in a quasi-static process $\Delta S=\frac{\Delta Q}{T}$ (where $\Delta Q$ is the small amount heat transfered and $T$ is the temperature of the gas in that process) and the relation $\Delta Q=\Delta U + p \Delta V$ between the small amount of heat transferred in a process ($\Delta Q$), the small change of internal energy of the ideal gas ($\Delta U$), the pressure of the gas in that process ($p$) and the small change in its volume ($\Delta V$), we can write:

$$\Delta S=\frac{\Delta Q}{T}=\frac{\Delta U + p \Delta V}{T}=\frac{n_{m}C_{v}\Delta T}{T}+\frac{n_{m}R\Delta V}{V}$$

We can now integrate this equation from state $1$ (entropy $S_1$, temperature $T_1$, volume $V_1$) to state $2$ (entropy $S_2$, temperature $T_2$, volume $V_2$). The integral $\int_{T_1}^{T_2} \frac{1}{T} \,dT$ is equal to $\ln \frac{T_2}{T_1}$ and the integral $\int_{V_1}^{V_2} \frac{1}{V} \,dV$ is equal to $\ln \frac{V_2}{V_1}$ so we get:

$$S_2-S_1=n_mC_v\ln \frac{T_2}{T_1}+n_mR\ln \frac{V_2}{V_1}$$

which is the formula that you asked about.

The only difference is that in your equation $m$ (which is the number of moles $n_m$ in my notation) is pulled out of the parenthesis and the states $S_1$ and $S_2$ are interchanged. The latter affects the sign: there's $-T_0(S_1-S_2)$, i.e. $T_0(S_2-S_1)$, from which you get $+T_0(C_v \ln \frac{T_2}{T_1}+R \ln \frac{V_2}{V_1})$ in the way I explained above.

### Additional question from the comment - https://ibb.co/GVqkJVb

Let's start with the derived formula $S_2-S_1=n_mC_v\ln \frac{T_2}{T_1}+n_mR\ln \frac{V_2}{V_1}$ and work our way to the expression from the photo. We'll use the fact that $C_p=C_v+R$, as well as $\frac{p_2}{T_2}=\frac{n_mR}{V_2}$ and $\frac{T_1}{p_1}=\frac{V_1}{n_mR}$.

$$S_1-S_2=n_mC_v\ln \frac{T_1}{T_2}+n_mR\ln \frac{V_1}{V_2}=n_m(R \ln(\frac{n_mR}{V_2} \frac{V_1}{n_mR})-C_v \ln \frac{T_2}{T_1})=n_m(R \ln(\frac{p_2}{T_2} \frac{T_1}{p_1})-C_v \ln \frac{T_2}{T_1})=n_m(R \ln \frac{p_2}{p_1}-R \ln \frac{T_2}{T_1}-C_v \ln \frac{T_2}{T_1})=n_m(R \ln \frac{p_2}{p_1}-C_p \ln \frac{T_2}{T_1})$$

We get the equivalent formula from the photo, scaled by $n_m$. It is possible to derive a couple of such equivalent formulae, which is mostly done using simple algebraic manipulations involving the $pV=n_mRT$ formula.

Comment: I get it but in some of the numerical problems, the formula is changed a bit I am giving you a link please check this out. - https://ibb.co/GVqkJVb, 
https://ibb.co/Qr4M8rz

Comment: Why did the minus sign appear?

Comment: I'll edit the post soon to include the explanation of the equations in those photos.

Comment: I have added the additional explanation you requested.

Comment: can you please explain to me the entropy generation?